# How to make lines be re-printed on in python while multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a file thats like this:

```
def runtask(task_num):
    print(('Task {} | Status: started').format(task_num))
    time.sleep(2)
    print(('Task {} | Status: doing something').format(task_num))
    time.sleep(1)
    print(('Task {} | Status: doing thing').format(task_num))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fiver = ['1', '2', '3','4','5']
    for i in fiver:
        Thread(target = runtask, args=i ).start()
```

Currently this prints every line separately at the same time, I was wondering if there was any way for each task to reprint on their own line?
So instead of it printing like:

```
Task 1 | Status: started
Task 2 | Status: started
Task 1 | Status: doing something
Task 2 | Status: doing something
Task 1 | Status: doing thing
Task 2 | Status: doing thing
```

It would send it like:

```
Task 1 | Status: started
Task 2 | Status: started
```

and then after 3 seconds, no new lines were reprinted but rather the status section was changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking at this in the future, I found a module that sorta helps with this problem. Its a cool library called [Rich](https://pypi.org/project/rich/), which makes really nice graphical cli outputs, such as task handling.